# size of picture windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

in my app i have a list of picture. I would like to determine the size of the single images but not have property.

```
using (MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary())
        {
            CameraRollAlbum = library.RootPictureAlbum.Albums.First((album) => album.Name == "Camera Roll");

            List<Picture> pictures = CameraRollAlbum.Pictures.Tolist();

            foreach (Picture pic in pictures)
                {
                   pic.size?? pic.length??
                }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the Image Stream eval the size:

```
 foreach (Picture pic in pictures)
                {
                   var sizeInKb = pic.GetImage().Length / 1024;
                }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.picture_members.aspx

Comment: I know, I need the image size. Can be calculated from height and width?